# Can i pass method name as argument with super?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a common controller for my application.

```
class CommonController < ApplicationController
  def index 
   # My stuff
  end
end
```

And in my other controller i am using super to call my index method like this.

```
class Other1Controller < CommonController
  def index
    super
  end
end

class Other2Controller < CommonController
  def index
    super
  end
end
```

This is working fine.

Now in my class i have two method index and index1.

```
class Other1Controller < CommonController
  def index
    super
  end

  def index1
    super(index) # Can i pass method inside super to override this method with my 
                 # common index method.
  end
end
```

Is there any way ? can i pass method with super to override my method with specific method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just call `index`?

```
class Other1Controller < CommonController
  def index
    super
  end

  def index1
    index
  end
end
```